# reliable method for table row overlay?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to figure out how to reliably (so, in the 4 major browsers) create an overlay that sits on top of table rows. What I've done so far seems to work in Chrome and Firefox but not in IE and Safari.

I have a table that has buttons in the left-most column that when clicked, trigger some logic that decides which rows to put the overlays on. The overlays (thus far) are `<div>` elements that I insert into the DOM right before the table row `<tr>` element. The markup ends up looking like this:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <tr>
      <td>Some text</td>
      <td>Some text</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the CSS I have for the overlay

```
div.overlay{
    background-color:#000000;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    height:28px;
    position:absolute;
    width:1136px;
    z-index:100;
    opacity: 0.7;
    filter: alpha(opacity=70);
    background:transparent;
    ms-filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#B2000000, endColorstr=#B2000000);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#B2000000, endColorstr=#B2000000);
    zoom:1;
}
```

Here's the result I get in Chrome 34 and Firefox 29 (good):
[image: Chrome/Firefox overlay result]

However, here is IE 11 (the overlays seem to go behind the rows):
[image: IE 11 overlay result]

And here is Safari on Windows (similar result to IE 11 but the overlays are a little off-positioned):
[image]

**Question**: Is there a better method of doing this that works consistently cross-browser? Or am I just missing some small details to get it to work in IE and Safari?

Comment: divs don't belong in tables. why not darken cells inside a tr with a certain class that can be easily toggled on and off? ex: tr.overlay td { background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); }

Comment: Well, I tend to agree, but I want to 'cover' the rows so nothing in the cells can be clicked and so there is that look to it of the non-choosable rows being covered.

Comment: then add user-select:none; (and xbrowser repeats), cursor: not-allowed; and  pointer-events: none; to the .overlay css class mentioned above. this avoid any size/scaling issues, absolute positioning and other outmoded table design headaches.

Comment: Yeah I'm starting to agree with your thinking after this headache. What do you mean by "(and xbrowser repeats)" ? cross-browser repeats?

Comment: webkit, moz and ie prefixes on top of css3.  in my experience, using js to manipulate sized widgets in/on/above table parts is like the holy grail in the last crusade, don't get sucked into something that's ultimately, barely beyond reach.

Comment: I ended up just going with dandavis's advice and just created a separate style for the row and all <td>'s within it. It looks a little different now, but it works.